# Read certain lines of a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON file with 50,000 lines. Every line is an object.

I would like to read in the first 5 lines.

The below code keeps giving me an error that I'm trying to load a list. What am I missing?

```
f = open('./flights.json', 'r').readlines()[:5]
dict = json.loads(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

If every line is an object, you have a JSONL or [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format file, not a JSON file.
`json.loads` will parse a single string that represents a single valid JSON value. It will not accept a list. This works (I have taken liberty to rename your variables appropriately):

```
five_values = [json.loads(line) for line in five_lines]
```